Shortcut to test the exit code of a command in one line
How to test if the exit code of a command equals a given value in one line?
I'm looking for an equivalent to the following without the need to run the command first and retrieve $?:
diff a.txt b.txt
if [ $? = 2 ]; then
  echo diff failed
  exit 2
fi

This is different from the following questions because this question is about checking if exit code is equal to a specific value rather than being zero or not:

Bash check return code of a command inline

Bash conditional based on exit code of command



There's no shortcut for differentiating between non-zero exit codes. You can write that like this though:
if diff a.txt b.txt; [ $? = 2 ]; then
  echo diff failed
  exit 2
fi


You can achieve this in a single line using the && and || operators. These operators allow you to execute a command and immediately test its exit status.
diff a.txt b.txt || { [ $? -eq 2 ] && echo "diff failed" && exit 2; }

